# NPE while getting InputStream used to pass Client_secret.json for GoogleClientSecrets

Tags: java, android

I am following Quickstart guide of Google Calendar API but stuck with my code as NPE on inputstream. This is exactly copy of code.

```
InputStream in = BGTask.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/client_secret.json");
                GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
                GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));
```

Pls help to fix , I read many blogs and questions giving different solution like put full path of path so I tried with that you like 
D:\Android Development\Mycalpp\app\client_Secret.json but none of them could able to fix this in Android studio.

BGTask is Class extends to AsyncTask. Here also in example 1 the same code is shown.

https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets

Comment: where is the file located?\

Comment: D:\Android Development\Mycalpp\app

Comment: normally in Android you are creating a FileInputStream or AssetStream when reading files from Assets or File Storage. Put the file in the assets folder and then `getAssetManager()` and create the `AssetStream` and then pass it to the `GoogleClientSecrets`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

**Option 1:**

Put the file(client_secret.json) in the assets/ folder.

Then read it like this:

```
    InputStream in = getAssets().open("client_secret.json");
    GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
            GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));
```

**Option 2:**

Put the file(client_secret.json) in the res/raw folder(if there is no raw folder create it).

Then read it like this:

```
Resources res = getResources();
InputStream in = res.openRawResource(R.raw.client_secret);
GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
            GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));
```

Hope it helps!!!

Answer (score -1):

`getResourceAsStream` is going to read a file from your classpath (not the source directory) so make sure that `client_secret.json`  is deployed along with your java classes and is on your classpath

Comment: D:\Android Development\Mycalpp\app\src\main\java\jss\Mycalpp\remin is path to my BGTask class and I coped the client_secret to this folder but still same error.

Comment: yes, this is a source directory and will not be on your classpath.  Find out where the classes and resources are copied to when you deploy.  The json file needs to be there